# Posso ter procedures com o mesmo nome e quantidade de parâmetros num mesmo package (ORACLE)?

Tags: banco-de-dados, oracle

Posso ter um package com duas procedures de mesmo nome, quantidade e tipo de parâmetros apenas diversificando o nome dos parâmetros?

Comment: Qual o sentido disso? O que vai mudar nelas além do nome dos parâmetros? Elas vão executar a mesma ação?

Comment: @Laerte, um sistema no qual estou dando manutenção está gerando um erro genérico o suficiente para não ajudar em nada. Creio que a causa do erro seja a tentativa de execução de uma procedure no cenário descrito. Obviamente não executam a mesma ação.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, é possível criar uma ou mais procedures, functions, etc... no mesmo escopo(Ex. package) tanto com a diferentes ou iguais quantidades de parâmetros, nomes e tipos.

O compilador irá chamar o subprograma na qual os parâmetros passados se identificam, tanto em quantidade ou tipo de valor, caso o tipo de um parâmetro não coincida com a declaração um erro será retornado.

Leia sobre este tema nas documentações da oracle:

[Overloading Packaged Subprograms](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96624/09_packs.htm#568)

[Overloading Subprogram Names](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96624/08_subs.htm#12353)